# Spoofing Transaction

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core

This transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2231b527b0063dd2c97472d6289038828db3d91a074c9dafe9e53bd5cf66cdfb has been reported as an event spoofing transaction - however it shows up on the safe app as a transfer but has no approvals from any owners. It seems like its spoofed but if so it shouldn't be shown as a transfer in the safe app.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question relates to Safe{Wallet} and should be pointed towards help.safe.global rather than on Stack Exchange using the `safe-core-sdk` or `safe-core` tags (which are reserved for questions relative to Safe{Core} SDK or infrastructure). Feel free to reach out to the support team there using the "chat" icon in the bottom-right corner of the page.

Hope it helps,
Louis